# How to login from Wordpress site to Codeigniter?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, authentication

I want to implement a login section in wp such a way that can also logged-in me in the Codeigniter site with is a sub-directory in may site. These two site (WP|CI) runs paralleled. If one user logged-in in WP then automatically he will be logged-in in the CI portal to. Assuming same user name and same password used.

Any suggestion most welcome.

Comment: For CodeIgniter and WordPress, do you maintain single database or separate database?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I've used separate database.

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same domain you can simply check for the needed cookies and confirm that data for a logged in user.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

You can check this cookies trough the CI Cookie library or simply with checking the $_COOKIE var, but you still need to verify this info with the WordPress database.

Comment: Thanks Neils. I'll try to implement this way.

Comment: I believe this approach with `wp_login` hook will solve the question.